# Incomplete Gamma function $\Gamma(0,x)$ and $\Gamma(0,-x)$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

I want to find the value of this
\begin{align}
y=\Gamma(0,x)-\Gamma(0,-x)
\end{align}
where $\Gamma$ is the upper incomplete Gamma function, $x>0$ is real. I can't find the definition of $\Gamma(0,-x)$ and the result $y$. Anyone who could help me with this is appreciated.

Comment: $\Gamma(0,x)=E_1(x)$ and $\Gamma(0,x)=\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\text{Ei}(-x)-i \pi  & x<0 \\
 -\text{Ei}(-x) & x>0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)$.

Comment: $\Gamma(0,x)-\Gamma(0,-x)=i\pi+2\int_0^x t^{-1}\sinh t \, dt$.